# What RDP clients support NAP to a Windows Server 2008 machine?

Tags: windows, rdp, remmina

I'm trying to connect up to a Windows Server 2008 machine over the internet with RDP secured by NAP.

The Remmina client doesn't appear to support this.

Can anyone suggest a client that does?

Answer (score 0):

The NAP capabilities of Windows Server 2008 will only allow connection of computers that fully meet the security requirements set by the administrator.

Remmina may fail to meet a security requirement. Try another rdp program:

itap mobile rdp (require license, try the trial edition)

http://itap-mobile.com/desktop/rdp